# Why are my cascading parameters interfering with one another?

Tags: c#, parameters, blazor, cascading

I select two different numbers from the drop-down lists (containing only numbers) and these are passed to the component via cascading parameters. On this component is displays the values that were chosen. BUT both variables are the same?!?! What am I doing wrong?

Component:

```
<p>number 1:@selectedNumberOne</p>


<p>number 2: @selectedNumberTwo</p>

@code {
    #region Cascading Parameter
    [CascadingParameter(Name="one")] //added name
    public int? selectedNumberOne { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter(Name="two")] //added name
    public int? selectedNumberTwo { get; set; }
    #endregion

   
}
```

index:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-2">
    <select class="fluent-input" @onchange="SelectNumberOne">
        @for (int i = 10; i < 20 + 9; i++)
        {
            <option value="@i">@i</option>       
        }
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-2">
    <select class="fluent-input" @onchange="SelectNumberTwo">
        @for (int i = 10; i < 20 + 9; i++)
        {
            <option value="@i">@i</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

<MudCard Elevation="1" Class="mb-5">
    <CascadingValue Value="selectedNumberOne" Name="one">
        <CascadingValue Value="selectedNumberTwo" Name="two">
            <TestComponent @ref="testComponent"></TestComponent>
        </CascadingValue>
    </CascadingValue>
</MudCard>

@code{
    TestComponent? testComponent;

    private int? selectedNumberOne { get; set; }
    async Task SelectNumberOne(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedNumberOne = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString());
    }

    private int selectedNumberTwo { get; set; }
    async Task SelectNumberTwo(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedNumberTwo = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I found an answer here: https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/blazor-multiple-cascading-parameters/

Comment: That and your code here is actually cascading the same variable twice `selectedNumberOne`. Look at the name parameter for both the attribute and CascadingValue

Comment: If I add names to the cascading parameter in the index page how is this referenced in the child component?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cascade-multiple-values

Comment: This works marvellously now. Thank you very much. I am very new to cascading parameters